# Get notified when value in List is updated using realm

Tags: swift, realm

I am trying to write an application in OS X using a Realm database. I want to trigger notification when where there is change in value of List which is inside another object

Below is the Class

```
final class Profile: Object {
    @objc dynamic var gradient1 = ""
    @objc dynamic var gradient2 = ""
    @objc dynamic var fontColor = ""
    @objc dynamic var selectedFont = ""
    @objc dynamic var selectedTitleFont = ""
    @objc dynamic var fontFamily = ""
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    @objc dynamic var shortbio = ""
    @objc dynamic var avatarSource = ""
    @objc dynamic var userid = ""
    @objc dynamic var email = ""
    var features = List<Features>()
    var socialLinkButtons = List<SocialLinkButtons>()

    @objc dynamic var appSelectedMetaData : AppMetaData? = nil

    override static func primaryKey() -> String?{
        return "userid"
    }

}

final class Features: Object {
    @objc dynamic var uuid = ""
    @objc dynamic var id = ""
    @objc dynamic var label = ""
    @objc dynamic var screen = ""
    @objc dynamic var active = false

    override static func primaryKey() -> String?{
        return "id"
    }

    convenience init(id: String, uuid: String, label: String, screen: String, active: Bool) {
        self.init()
        self.id = id
        self.uuid = uuid
        self.label = label
        self.screen = screen
        self.active = active
    }
}
```

I want to trigger notifications whenever value inside feature is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Realm Collection Notifications](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest#collection-notifications) to achieve your goals. You just need to make sure that you store the returned `NotificationToken` in a variable that doesn't get deallocated until you don't actually need to receive the notifications anymore and that you call `.invalidate()` on the token when you no longer want to receive notifications.

```
func observeFeatureChanges(in profile:Profile) -> NotificationToken {
    let notificationToken = profile.features.observe { changes in
        switch changes {
        case .update(_, deletions: let deletionIndices, insertions: let insertionIndices, modifications: let modIndices):
            print("Objects deleted from indices: \(deletionIndices)")
            print("Objects inserted to indices: \(insertionIndices)")
            print("Objects modified at indices: \(modIndices)")
        case .error(let error):
            print(error)
        case .initial(let type):
            print(type)
        }
    }
    return notificationToken
}
```